# How to Solve this?

Tags: github-pages

[image]

Deceptive site ahead
Attackers on akshitmodhiya.github.io may trick you into doing something dangerous like installing software or revealing your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, or credit cards). Learn more

Deceptive site ahead
Attackers on akshitmodhiya.github.io may trick you into doing something dangerous like installing software or revealing your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, or credit cards). Learn more

Answer (score 0):

Google thinks your site is a phishing site, or otherwise deceptive in some way. They have [advice on fixing it here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/security/social-engineering)

Comment: i tried but same issue